# Read and hexdump a symlink itself

Tags: linux, terminal, symlink

I spent 30 minutes looking at how to cat/hexdump read a symlink file itself, not the target, but the symlink itself, the tool(cat, hexdump, etc.) should not resolve the symlink, can someone help me out with this, please?

Comment: I do not understand.  What do you mean by "cat symlink file itself"? Does symlink file has "content" you can "read"?

Comment: Yes, I want to explore/copy its bytes. I can move the symlink to windows and see it there but I want to see the symlink file contents on Linux.

Comment: You can't. A symlink has no "bytes". Or in other words, the (generic) input/output api doesn't expose tools to inspect how symlink (or any file on a filesystem) is stored. Such operation would be filesystem specific - write an application that will use specific filesystem api to get such information, if you want. `I can move the symlink to windows and see it there` How do you "move" it and what tools to you use to "see it" and what do you see?

Comment: I am surprised you tell me this, there are tools that offer a --no-follow switch, they must be doing it someway, for example aws cli has a --no-follow-symlinks options for many of his commands for example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html moreover, a symlink can't be a 0 bytes file, it contains some metadata.

Comment: `they must be doing it someway` Well, you take `/a/path/to/some/file`. You query it's type with `stat()`(or `lstat()`). Och, it's a symlink! You query destination with `readlink()`. Then you either go to the directory or create a new symlink with same destination. No one "inspects bytes that are stored in a symlink", there are apis so that no one has to do that. `it contains some metadata` Yes, but these matadata are not visible from userspace. And each filesystem does it differently.

Comment: `or copy the symlink` what do you mean with that if it is not reading the symlink itself?

Comment: By "copy" I mean create a new symlink with `symlink(2)` with the same destination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216533/discussion-between-melardev-and-kamilcuk).

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't support sym-links in the same way that linux does. On Linux, they are apart of the file-system, and how they are apart of the file-system varies based on the file system.

For instance, here is how they are handled on Ext2:

> https://flylib.com/books/en/2.48.1/symbolic_link.html

To query symlinks in Linux, the primary method is through the lstat system call. From userland, `ls -al` tends to do a good job, although YMMV. Lastly, Linux supports both symbolic and hard links, which while externally similar are very different beasts.

Comment: I finally found something interesting that does not fit with your statement: https://paper.seebug.org/104/ you can translate it with Google translator, it is about a bug on Gitlab CVE-2016-9086, how do explain a symlink is embedded in the tar file?